Using a 24V dimmer with 12V
I have a Paulmann 70975 24V LED touch dimmer that I want to use with 12V LEDs. The input voltage is provided by a MeanWell LPV-60-12 12V 5A power supply. The consumer is a 12V 2835 white LED stripe of about 4.5m. Here are pictures of the dimmer:


The input voltage is split for the controller circuit and reduced to 5V using a 78L05 voltage regulator. The output is regulated by the controller using a FQD50N06 MOSFET.
Judging from the components' datasheets, everything should work fine with 12V.
It worked as expected at first, but after a few hours the switch becomes hot and won't react anymore. The LEDs are still on at the same brightness, but can't be dimmed or turned off. After disconnecting the power supply and waiting for a day, the switch still won't work anymore, LEDs still at the same brightness.
What am I missing? I also tried with another dimmer and another power supply of the same type. Still the dimmer becomes unresponsive after a few hours.

Update
The LEDs draw 2.6A (measured without dimmer) which should be within the specs of the MOSFET.
Here are the schematics. Photodiode = LED. Sorry in advance, I don't have a good program for that, suggestions welcome ;)


Update 2
I measured some values:
The 78L05 has an output of 3.8V, not 5V, which seems strange.
The FQD50N06 has 0.25-0.3V at the gate (depending on "on" or "off"), measured from source, which probably seems not to be enough threshold?
So any suggestions for different voltage divider resistors?

Your link claims the dimmer should handle 144W@24V, which is 6A. I wonder, how many W your LED strip draws? I assume you are not overloading your 5A 12V power supply, so that is probably not the issue. Next idea: What about the MOSFET gate voltage? 24V is probably outside spec of most, so perhaps there is a voltage divider, which lowers 24V to safe levels, let's say half. But from 12V source, the gate might become too low, resulting in poor conductivity and excessive power dissipation on the MOSFET.

If you have very heavy load, you could consider to replace the MOSFET in the top left hand corner with a beefier one.

That MOSFET can easily handle the current but needs Vgs of 10V to do it, while absolute max Vgs is 20V. I suggest you figure out the schematic so you can see if this is going to be an issue on a 12V supply. It seems likely.

Continuing from Finbarr's comment, I think it's likely that R5 & R6 form a voltage divider to drive the MOSFET's gate with a voltage lower than 20V when given a 24V supply. With you only providing a 12V supply, that gate voltage drive is now likely lower than 10V. Perhaps R3 & R4 are involved too. If you can trace the circuit around that area we might be able to suggest some modifications to get the gate voltage back up where it belongs to make the MOSFET switch properly and not dissipate a lot of power unnecessarily.

The MCU drives the MOSFET directly with 5V level via R5, there should be no difference at suply voltages between 12 and 24 V. FQD50N06 from VBsemi should be full conducting above 4 V, FQD50N06 from ISC probably not.

What did Paulmann's say when you aske them the question on their support centre web page?

@PeterJennings They would probably say something like it is designed for 24V, not for 12V...

With a supply of ~12.0V the voltage at the Gate is ~11.3V when the switch is "off" and ~12.0 when it is "on". Whilst turning "on" and "off" does not change anything at the output which is about ~9.2V

The schematic would not work drawn as that. Your MOSFET source is tied to ground and will just pass current though the body diode.

@winny sorry, my bad. fixed it

No worries! Technically correct, but very hard to read. For future reference, try drawing all schematics with ground on bottom of the page and your highest voltage at the top, with signal flow flow left to right.

I think I found the problem. There was a voltage drop before the 78L05 due to R1. With 24V input it worked, but 12V was not enough. I removed the resistor and now it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the help!
